# Error with HTML5 Audio

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am trying to do TTS with Google Translate URL service.

Below is the code Javascript code.

```
function longSentenceSpeak(text)
{
    var string = text.trim().split(" ").join("+");
    var finalString = string.replace(";",",")
    var url = "http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q="+finalString;

    var audio = document.getElementById('audio');

    var source = document.getElementById('source');
    source.src=url;

    audio.load(); //call this to just preload the audio without playing
    audio.play(); //call this to play the song right away
}
```

Below is my HTML

TODO supply a title

```
    <script src="scripts/TTS.js"></script>
    <script>
       function longText()
       {
           longSentenceSpeak("hello world ");
       }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <audio id="audio">
        <source id="source" src="" type="audio/wav" />
    </audio>

    <div><button onclick="longText()">Click me</button></div>
</body>
```

However this simply do not work, seems like HTML 5 audio is unable to handle the URL. When I run this code I get the below error.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (12:49:15:455 | error, network)
  at http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=hello
```

But I am sure the URL is correct, because you can try this

http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=hello%20world

Below is the JS Fiddle Link

http://jsfiddle.net/f1hgk5sc/

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: I actually got an error: http://i.imgur.com/k94RKFV.png, sometimes it worked, sometimes this.

Answer (score 1):

Well i just copied your code and everything works great.

```js
function longSentenceSpeak(text) {
  var string = text.trim().split(" ").join("+");
  var finalString = string.replace(";", ",")
  var url = "http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=" + finalString;

  var audio = document.getElementById('audio');

  var source = document.getElementById('source');
  source.src = url;

  audio.load(); //call this to just preload the audio without playing
  audio.play(); //call this to play the song right away
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function longText() {
      longSentenceSpeak("hello world ");
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <audio id="audio">
    <source id="source" src="" type="audio/wav" />
  </audio>

  <div>
    <button onclick="longText()">Click me</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: there is no sound.. Give the error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (14:45:09:044 | error, network)
  at http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=hello+world

Comment: Which web browser do you use?

Comment: In that case it must be some sort of browser incompatibility. I've checked it on Firefox.

Comment: Here [link](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-voices/issues/detail?id=21#c4) you can find more informations about your problem.